# How can I make my error pages look more friendly?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .Net Core + Entity Framework app that allows the user to see lists of engine production and also edit certain things.

If there are no errors, everything looks great.

But when I have an error, it uses an ugly view instead of my normal view.

Here is an example of a controller that looks great when there are no errors, but if there are errors, it's just black text on a white background.

Is there anyway to make it fit in with the rest of my web app?

Thanks!

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,EngineName,FactoryName")] ProductionRound productionRound)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Update(productionRound);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ProductionRoundExists(productionRound.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(productionRound);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom an error page and use `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` and `UseExceptionHandler` middleware to execute the error page like below:

View(`StatusCode.cshtml` located in `Views/Shared` folder):

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <h1 class="alert-heading">
        <span>This is a user-friendly error page :)</span>
    </h1>
    Error code: @ViewData["code"]
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [Route("Error/{statusCode}")]
    public IActionResult StatusCodeError(int statusCode)
    {
        ViewData["code"] = statusCode;
        return View("StatusCode");
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/500");

    //other middleware...
}
```